# Resolve conflict between multiple YouTube Playlist plugin instances

Tags: javascript, youtube

I have a page which uses a custom YouTube playlist plugin found here https://github.com/Giorgio003/Youtube-TV

When I have a single instance of the player on a page it works great, but if I try to add two or more players, only one will render.

This is a sample page with two playlists:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>YouTube TV</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="assets/ytv.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                background: #eee;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            .test-title{
                margin-bottom: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-11">
                    <div>
                        <h4 class="test-title">Testing Responsive YouTube Playlist</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="responsive1"></div>

                    <div id="responsive2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="src/ytv.js"></script>
        <script>
            var apiKey = 'ThisIsAValidKey';
            window.onload = function(){
                window.controller = new YTV('responsive1', {
                    playlist: 'PLaK7th3DkkqgBtr94FWKF5HNlbNIHWkww',
                    responsive: true
                });
            };
            window.onload = function(){
                window.controller = new YTV('responsive2', {
                    playlist: 'PLQJ-H2JR5Kwzv7Rdx2Ob-7Af5t3c2S_MN',
                    responsive: true
                });
            };

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I moved the API key out of ytv.js into a global variable.

```
// Set apiKey as global var
// var apiKey = 'ThisIsAValidKey';
```

Other than that, the js is the same as found [here](https://github.com/Giorgio003/Youtube-TV/blob/master/src/ytv.js).

How can I modify this plugin to allow multiple instances?

**Update:**
I have also renamed the `window` vars with no change in result.

```
window.controller1 = new YTV(...);
window.controller2 = new YTV(...);
```

**Solution:**
As inferred from the marked answer below

```
window.onload = function(){
    $('#responsive1').ytv({
        playlist: 'PL6x-m6zFmZvueGe7XnT0z1Qlsn2zUs5_F',
        responsive: true
    });
    $('#responsive2').ytv({
        playlist: 'PLQJ-H2JR5Kwzv7Rdx2Ob-7Af5t3c2S_MN',
        responsive: true
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the Youtube code, I could see it already handles multiple jQuery instance.

```
if ((typeof jQuery !== 'undefined')) {
    jQuery.fn.extend({
        ytv: function(options) {
            return this.each(function() {
                new YTV(this.id, options);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I created a quick fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pj8kpbzw/
Please check the console as it prints two instances.

Comment: I see that your example does print 2 objects, however, I am not able to get this to show up in the example provided in the question.

Comment: Ah, ok... I was able to get it to work. The JQuery call method accepts only the options object - not `id` and `opts`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to attach it to a window.controller! Instead of window.onload, you may use $(document).ready and just invoke the ytv instance. Would that work?

Comment: Thanks! I was just using the method provided in the plugin demo. It seems there is a built in jquery method to instantiate the playlists which works better. I updated the question with the working code.